# How to stub gmaps4rails geocode functions in rspec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, gmaps4rails

I'm using gmaps4rails, and trying to develop some tests.

I have a factory

```
factory :country do
   sequence(:name) { |n| "Country#{n}" }
end
```

which is obviously not recognized by Google.

```
Validation failed: Gmaps4rails address Address invalid
```

The API calls are also taking time to run in my tests.

How can I stub the API call out?

I've tried adding

```
before(:each)
  Country.stub(:geocode)
end
```

to the spec file but it has no effect.

My model looks like this

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable :lat => 'latitude', :lng => 'longitude'
  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.name}" 
  end
  geocoded_by :gmaps4rails_address

  after_validation :geocode
end
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to do with integers in the name.

I guess the address is absent or invalid.

Anyway, there are plenty of ways to either skip geocoding or stub it.

Take inspiration from the [gem's specs](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/spec/models/user_spec.rb)

Comment: Hi apneadiving. thanks for the answer. Seems that the invalid address is a response from Google. Does this sound right? So how do I stub geocoding? I'm running a single test country_specs.rb, in which I have a before :each block that contains `Country.stub(:geocode)`. I've tried a few other things `.stub_geocode`, `.stub(:gmaps4rails)`, etc. But geocoding is still being run. I'll add my model code to the question. Appreciate any suggestions you have

Comment: it comes from the gem. For stubbing look here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/spec/support/geocoding.rb

Comment: actually I spoke too soon. I'm still seeing API calls in my test. I've tried adding `Geocoding.stub_gecoding` and `Gmaps4rails.stub!(:geocode).and_return [mock_address]` Scratching my head! Is there any documentation on testing with gmaps-4-rails that I've overlooked?

Comment: `Gmaps4rails.stub(:geocode)` should be enough. Again loik at my specs, there is nothing more and it works fine

Comment: ok, thanks for the confirmation. I thought it should work. I must be doing something wrong elsewhere. Will keep digging :) Thanks for the help, and a great gem

Comment: just to close this, I finally tracked down my issue. I was trying `Gmaps4rails.stub(:geocode).and_return [stuff]` but still getting API calls. I'm in the process of moving from geocoder to gmaps4rails, and had overlooked some old methods. Geocoder was to blame (well, me really). Thanks again, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: As  I look at those specs, it appears that you set the options at the begining of the spec file; but is there any way to disable geocoding for *all* specs, unless explicitly requested?   Sort of like the "no_peeping_toms" gem for observers?

Comment: @DGM: nope I didn't code anything in this scope. You can disable it if you pass `false` to `process_geocoding` which could be a lambda or method configured conditionnaly to Rails env

Comment: Oh, in the model, pass false in test environnment?   Or perhaps have test environment monkey patch it on load?