# How to stub Gmap4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, gmaps4rails

I want to implement a rspec test for a ruby on rails project. Some of the classes uses gmaps4rails

factories.rb:

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :place do |s|
      sequence(:name) {|n| "test  place#{n}" }
   end
 end
```

factorytest_spec.rb (with require 'spec_helper')

```
it "Test" do
Place.any_instance.stub(:geocode).and_return("..")
  8.times do
    s = FactoryGirl.build(:shop_with_adress)
  end
end
```

Now this code sometimes goes through green, sometimes not.

```
 Failure/Error: s = FactoryGirl.build(:place)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
```

this seems to boild down to a `Gmaps4rails Adress invalid` error (?)
How should I stub gmaps4rails? I don't really get how to apply the hints from [How to stub gmaps4rails geocode functions in rspec tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713434/how-to-stub-gmaps4rails-geocode-functions-in-rspec-tests) exactly.. Maybe because I'm quite new to stubbing/rspec.

Comment: look here: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/spec/support/geocoding.rb#L29

Comment: Okay, yes, thanks - this how you tests your gem. How do I work with this? Should I include this geocoding module in my support folder (how do I do so, just copy?)? Do I just have to add this *args thing to my stubbed method? I am not sure what to do with this, sorry :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could copy the stub on `Gmaps4rails.geocode` detailled [here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/spec/support/geocoding.rb#L29) and adapt it to your needs if necessary.

For customization, copy paste the result of:

```
Gmaps4rails.geocode("your custom address")
```

Which is an Array and copy it:

```
Gmaps4rails.stub(:geocode) do |*args|
  your_custom_array
end
```

Obviously, I recommend, like in the gem, to create your own spec support module.

Comment: Thank you :) At least inline it works now.. Will try to refactor it in its own module